# What is the equivalent of @@ERROR in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

What is the equivalent of `@@ERROR` in SQL Server for POSTGRESQL?

Could we assume that ERRCODE in Postgresql is equivalent of `@@ERROR` in SQL Server?

Comment: Check if this helps you https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: Even in T-SQL it's better to use try/catch

Comment: Please see [Migrate your mind set too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). As far as "Could we assume that ERRCODE in Postgresql is equivalent of @@ERROR in SQL Server?" **Absolutely not**. For example a check constraint violation SQL Server generated @@Error = 547, but the same error in Postgres generates SQLSTATE of '23514'  (there is no errcode) See Postgres Documentation: [Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/errcodes-appendix.html).